# How DispatchProxy compare to Castle DynamicProxy?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

Some time ago I published an open source library which heavily relies on *Castle DynamicProxy*. Now that .NET Core 1.x RTM is out, I don't find how I could support .NET Core (Castle DynamicProxy still doesn't work on .NET Core...), until I met [`DispatchProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.reflection.dispatchproxy) class.

Actually there's no comprehensive documentation about the whole class, and it seems like it's too limited compared to *Castle DynamicProxy*.

In my case, I would need to intercept property setters, and implement some interfaces in generated proxies during run-time.

Does `DispatchProxy` meet these requirements? Or, what could be a working alternative to generate proxies during run-time on .NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is obsolete because I could solve the issue integrating Castle Core 4.x which already provided support to .NET Core!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wanting to work with Castle Core and Net Core for generating proxies - there is a GitHub project that simplifies the whole process. [SimpleProxy](https://github.com/f135ta/SimpleProxy)

**[Disclaimer: I am the developer of this project]**